# Isn't "to be mistaken" ambiguous?

Tags: word-usage, differences, adjectives, ambiguity, passive-voice

Please follow the reasoning.

Active voice:

> My neighbors (always) mistake me for my brother.
>   That's why they
>   call me Jim.

Passive voice:

> I am mistaken for my brother (by my neighbors).
>   That's why I'm
>   called Jim.

Hence:

> If I'm not mistaken, I wouldn't be called Jim.

But there is an idiomatic expression:

> If I'm not mistaken, his name is John.

So if my reasoning is correct, *to be mistaken* has two meanings:

- to be mistaken for something/someone (verb)
- to be wrong (adjective)

Maybe that's why this expression confuses so many English learners.

Note: I've read many related topics on different sites including this one. And I couldn't find a proper answer yet. This Q can hardly be considered a *duplicate* as the other related Qs are about *mistaking* vs *mistaken*.

Comment: You're right -- if you try hard enough you can make the sentence ambiguous.

Comment: I don't think that you can remove the "for s.b." part. You need the object, otherwise the [meaning changes](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mistake).

Comment: @Laurel According to `www.merriam-webster.com` the verb `mistake` not only has the transitive form without a second object: `mistook her way in the dark` but has the intransitive form too: `you mistook when you thought I laughed at you`. See https://goo.gl/iypKmP

Comment: @MarkusMarvell But they have different meanings...

Comment: @Laurel  Yes, you are right. But it does not affect the issue. I can give another example which seems doesn't change meaning: `They (usually) mistake me when i'm chewing. I'm mistaken (by them) when i'm chewing. If i'm not mistaken I'd have more friends.`

Comment: "If I'm not mistaken i wouldn't be called Jim." is not what we would say, given the context.  we would say "If I'm not mistaken *for my brother* (by other people) i wouldn't be called Jim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The confusion arises from the vagaries of English vocabulary and from two similar syntactic forms.  Forms first.

1. Subject Copulative-verb Nominative-Complement

A copulative (or linking) verb is a verb of being or feeling, and it links the complement to the subject, either identifying the subject (if the complement is a noun) or describing the state of the subject (if the complement is an adjective).

> **[1a]** I am John.
>   **[1b]** I am happy.

In 1a, John and I are the same person; in 1b, I am filled with happiness.

2. Subject **(** Auxiliary-Verb Past-Participle **)** **[** *by* Agent **]**

This is the form of a sentence in the passive voice. I've placed the auxiliary verb and past participle in **bold** parentheses to indicate that they go together to form the predicate. In the passive voice, the subject is acted upon by the verb, and the actor is given as the object of a prepositional phrase with *by*. I've called the actor Agent, and enclosed the prepositional phrase in bold brackets to indicate that it may be missing.

> **[2a]** I **(** am wounded **)** by an arrow.
>   **[2b]** The President **(** is elected **)** in years divisible by four.

In 2a, the subject has been hurtfully acted upon by a weapon. In 2b, the subject receives the action of selection for office, but the selectors are not mentioned. We may assume it's voters, and we could supply the missing phrase *by the voters*.

Confusion may arise because past participles, in addition to signaling the passive voice, may also act as noun modifiers like adjectives. Consider

> **[3a]** I am depressed.
>   **[3b]** I **(** am depressed **)** by events.

3a is like 1b. 3a says that I am suffering from a disease called depression. (I am filled with sad feelings that may have no external agent.)

3b is like 2b. 3b says that external events have acted upon me to make me sad.

But when no agent appears, how do we know which of the templates 1b and 2b to choose? We have to rely on the context. Sometimes the topic makes it obvious, e.g., elections always have agents (called electors or voters) who do the electing. Sometimes it takes knowing English usage and idiom, and that's what it takes for your example.

The *OED* tells us that the verb *to mistake* is an old one, with almost 700 years in the language, and originally it had two meanings -- to misidentify and to make an error. But over time, some forms fell out of favor and were no longer used. We no longer say *I mistake* to mean I made an error. That form is reserved to mean *I misidentified* as in your example. We say instead *I made a mistake* for being in the wrong.

The past participle *mistaken* moved in the opposite direction, and it no longer means *I am misidentified* unless it's accompanied by a prepositional phrase with *for*, again as in your example. Alone, it means I am in error.

Thus, if you find *am mistaken* by itself, it cannot be a passive form of the verb meaning *was misidentified*, and you must analyze the sentence by the pattern of 1b. On the other hand, if you find *am mistaken* with a prepositional phrase with *for*, it must be a passive form, and you must analyze the sentence by the pattern of 2a or 2b, depending on whether the agent is identified in a prepositional phrase with *by*.

Comment: Lucidly. I should admit you are right about `to be in error` and `to misidentify`. But the verb `mistake` seems has one more meaning: `to misinterpret` (https://goo.gl/iypKmP). And this one still confuses me. Since I could say: `My readers always mistake me. That's why they write those angry comments. So i tell my students, If the author is not mistaken (by readers) they have higher ratings`. The last sentence seems can be understood both in meaning `If the author is right they have higher ratings` and also in meaning `When the author is interpreted correctly they have higher ratings`.

Comment: @MarkusMarvell You're right about *to mistake* having the meaning *to misinterpret*, and according to the *OED*, the participle *mistaken* was used in a straightforward transformation to mean *misinterpreted*. But that's now archaic.

Answer (score 4):

### It depends on the context

When you say, "if I'm not mistaken..." I am going to conclude you mean "assuming I am not in error." This expression is very common in the native English vernacular of the US and likely other areas as well.

When taking about identities, to be understood I would avoid using the phrase "if I'm not mistaken." Instead, I would replace words as necessary to avoid confusion.  Often replacing"if" with "when" will be sufficient.

**"When** I'm not mistaken for Tom people don't treat me like a jerk."

The "for Tom" is an additional contextual clue that the meaning is different.

Seldom if ever will there be cause for a native speaker of American English to be confused by this expression.

Comment: `To mistake` has also the meaning to misinterpret. Example: `Don't mistake me, I mean exactly what I said (from goo.gl/iypKmP). So in case `My readers always mistake me. That's why they write those angry comments`. We can produce the following passive voice sentence: `If I'm not mistaken (by readers) I have a higher ratings`. This is exactly the case where the meaning of If I'm not mistaken seems confusingly ambiguous. Isn't it? Though of course it can be fixed by replacing if with when as you've noticed.

Comment: "If I'm not mistaken" = "If I'm not in error" in British English, too.

Comment: @MarkusMarvell That would be unidiomatic. "If I'm not mistaken, I have higher ratings" means "I believe I have higher ratings"; if you wanted to express the idea that you have higher ratings unless your readers misunderstand, you'd probably say "If my readers don't mistake me, I have higher ratings." Actually, I'd probably say "misunderstand" rather than "mistake" in that case -- "mistake" in that sense seems a little old-fashioned (but that might just be me).

Answer (score 1):

yes it is ambiguous.  it can mean either "in error" ("if I'm not mistaken") or "wrongly taken", i.e. "I'm often mistaken for my brother.

Comment: I disagree. "Mistaken" means "in error"; "mistaken _for_" means "wrongly taken".

Comment: @David Richerby:  "He's been mistaken for years about that."

Comment: That's not an example of "mistaken for"; it's just a sentence in which the word "mistaken" happens to be followed by "for". The "for" goes with "years", not "mistaken", as you can see either by rephrasing as "He's been mistaken about that for years" (which, IMO, is a more natural phrasing), by trying to delete "years" (leading to "He's been mistaken for about that", which is nonsense) or by replacing the adjective "mistaken" with something else (e.g., "He's been angry for years about that" -- there's no such thing as "angry for").

Comment: "mistaken for" is not a word.  "He was mistaken for."  So "for" goes with the following word: "He was mistaken [for Clark Gable]", not "He was [mistaken for] Clark Gable".

Comment: "For Clark Gable" is also not a word... To "mistake for" is a [phrasal verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb). So, actually, the grammatical unit _is_ "mistaken for".

Comment: the question was about "mistaken", not "mistaken for".  the fact that it's meaning depends on context shows that it is indeed systematically ambiguous,  IMHO. you may disagree,  no prob, let's agree to disagree.

Comment: The question is precisely about the distinction between "mistaken" and "mistaken for". The asker didn't phrase it that way, presumably because they were unaware that "mistake for" is a phrasal verb.

Comment: or, just possibly, the OP asked his/her question and not yours.  let's drop it, we've given the OP sufficient info to draw an independent conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "to be mistaken" not ambiguous because in English, just as in all other language, you may find context clues when speaking or reading. You are referring to the same arrangement of words that convey different meanings, but they are different versions, if you will, of the word mistaken. Mistaken can mean *to be viewed* incorrectly, or *to view* incorrectly. Notice, I used the word "view" in both definitions. The same word, only given a second meaning. Likewise, you need only look to context clues to figure out which "version" of "mistaken" you are reading/hearing/speaking.

Comment: What about that. `My readers always mistake me. That's why they write those angry comments`. So: `If I'm not mistaken (by readers) I have a higher ratings`. Isn't it confusingly ambiguous?

Comment: @MarkusMarvell "My readers always mistake me" sounds weird.  Better would be "My readers always misunderstand me".